# How to expand horizontal data to vertical in dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I has a text file. Now, I want expand horizontal data to be vertical. 
Using the fields from the first field of the specified file as the key, the horizontally arranged field data is expanded vertically and rearranged. What should I do?

This is my input:

```
0000000 aa______ 50 F 91 59 20 76 
0000001 bb______ 50 F 46 39 8 5 
0000003 cc______ 26 F 30 50 71 36 
0000004 dd______ 40 M 58 71 20 10
```

Exp1: Now, I want to develop vertically for every 2 fields with the first value kept on each row. I want to have the desired output result as below.

```
0000000 aa______ 50 
0000000 F 91 
0000000 59 20 
0000000 76 
0000001 bb______ 50 
0000001 F 46 
0000001 39 8 
0000001 5 
0000003 cc______ 26 
0000003 F 30 
0000003 50 71 
0000003 36 
0000004 dd______ 40 
0000004 M 58 
0000004 71 20 
0000004 10
```

Exp2: Same as above, but keeping the first two values on each row.

```
0000000 aa______ 50 F 
0000000 aa______ 91 59 
0000000 aa______ 20 76 
0000001 bb______ 50 F 
0000001 bb______ 46 39 
0000001 bb______ 8 5 
0000003 cc______ 26 F 
0000003 cc______ 30 50 
0000003 cc______ 71 36 
0000004 dd______ 40 M 
0000004 dd______ 58 71 
0000004 dd______ 20 10
```

This is my code, but it not working in correct.

```
val df = sc.textFile("/home/ubuntu/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.6/data.txt"); 
val splitRdd = df.map{s => val a = s.split("[ |]") 
var i = 0; 
val date = Array(a(i) + " " + a(i+1) + " " + a(i+2) + " " + a(i+3) + " " + a(i+4)) 
(date ++ a.takeRight(0)).mkString(" ") 
} 
splitRdd.foreach(println)
```

Comment: As you have seen now for the third time: don't wrap everything in `<pre>` tags. Take a look at your questions and how others edited them, and make your future posts accordingly. Basically: only use code formatting for code, and leave the rest as plain text (thus also outside `<pre>` tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be easiest to solve using an `UDF`:

```
def splitValues(nKeys: Int, nGroup: Int) = udf((str: String) => {
  val vals = str.split(" ")
  val key = vals.take(nKeys)
  vals.drop(nKeys).grouped(nGroup).toSeq.map(e => (key ++ e).mkString(" "))
})
```

The `UDF` takes two inputs, `nKeys` which is how many values to use as the key and `nGroup` which is the number of values to keep on each row (in addition to the keys). This `UDF` will return an array, so you need to use `explode` after applying it.

Usage example with one key value:

```
val df = spark.read.text("test.txt")
df.select(explode(splitValues(1, 2)($"value")))

+-------------------+
|col                |
+-------------------+
|0000000 aa______ 50|
|0000000 F 91       |
|0000000 59 20      |
|0000000 76         |
|0000001 bb______ 50|
|0000001 F 46       |
|0000001 39 8       |
|0000001 5          |
|0000003 cc______ 26|
|0000003 F 30       |
|0000003 50 71      |
|0000003 36         |
|0000004 dd______ 40|
|0000004 M 58       |
|0000004 71 20      |
|0000004 10         |
+-------------------+
```

With two key values:

```
df.select(explode(splitValues(2, 2)($"value")))

+----------------------+
|col                   |
+----------------------+
|0000000 aa______ 50 F |
|0000000 aa______ 91 59|
|0000000 aa______ 20 76|
|0000001 bb______ 50 F |
|0000001 bb______ 46 39|
|0000001 bb______ 8 5  |
|0000003 cc______ 26 F |
|0000003 cc______ 30 50|
|0000003 cc______ 71 36|
|0000004 dd______ 40 M |
|0000004 dd______ 58 71|
|0000004 dd______ 20 10|
+----------------------+
```